# Replacing a field value in one file by matching another field in another file

Tags: unix

I have a file `text1` where fields are like:

```
box|domain|service|Consumer|organisation
```

Eg.for two such fields:

```
Datapower|utility|accountLog|verizon|google  
Datapower|utility|accountLog|veri|google
```

Another lookup file `text2` which is used for mapping is like:

```
Verizon|myself
```

What I am looking for is whenever fourth field verizon exists in `text1` it should be replaced by second field myself using the mapping done in lookup file `text2`. But at the same time, I also need to keep in mind that if no matching is found for veri in `text1` by doing lookup in `text2`, that row should be printed as such. Please suggest.

Thanks,
MT

Comment: You've apparently have heard that StackOverflow.com is a free coding service. Sorry, its not (even though free coding happens all the time). You'll need to indicate what (computer) language you want to use, AND you should add a tag for that language. I'd recommend spending an hour or two reading thru questions here with the `awk` tag, as similar questions (with slightly different terms) get asked all the time. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, as it's my first post so will tc from next time on. I am using k shell for scripting; I am aware how awk will be used for matching and replacement, the only problem I am facing is when there isn't a match found in the lookup file and printing the row as such from the main file. Could you help with that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to read first the whole files into two vectors with structure elements and then make the specified changes on it. Finally rewrite all into the same file.
The stepping file operations are hard in text files and in this case also the exchange of words would be difficult having they different lengths.

Comment: Please elaborate with reference to the example given

Comment: Could anyone please with this situation? I checked this forum for similar questions but that didn't help as everything is related to replacement when match but not retaining the rows when there isn't a match.